# google OAuth API to fetch users youtube account details

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I've been trying to fetch account details of a user using Oauth apis provided by googleapis, is there any way to do so, i used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library package to fetch the auth-token after the user login. I want to get the access of user's youtube account details like followers, channels and videos using the google auth mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api that returns a users YouTube account details like followers, channels and videos.  That kind of information would be considered private in my opinion and something Google probably wants to keep to themselves.